# Oracle Apex - Select List on Interactive Grid

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Interactive Grid with a really simple select list (two values only):

No
Submitted

This is an editable IG, when I click on my select list column the value automatically changes to 'No' (which is the one displayed first out of the two options) regardless of what I have on that row.
E.g.

This is row 1:

[image]

It had 'Submitted' as its value, but when I double clicked to edit, it automatically changed to 'No'.
Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks

(using Apex 22.1.3)

Comment: Can you create a new workspace on apex.oracle.com and reproduce this issue ?